# Idomatic expression for “less and less”

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there an idiomatic way to translate “less and less”. I.e., I want to say that something happens less frequently than before and it is in continual decline. For example:

> People are using Facebook less and less.

I think in French you could say “de moins en moins”.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way would be to use "pli kaj pli", which is idiomatic in Esperanto, and then just take the opposite of what you wanted to say.

> Homoj uzas Facebook pli kaj pli malofte.

That said, that has a slightly different intensional meaning. I haven't really heard of a more direct equivalent, though. I suppose it would have to be,

> Homoj uzas Facebook malpli kaj malpli (ofte).

...but that doesn't really sound as good, probably because of the fact that *malpli* has two syllables, or just perhaps it isn't used much, from what I can tell. Still, I suppose you could introduce it; you would be understood, at least.

Comment: “Malpli kaj malpli” actually has loads of hits in the Tekstaro. So I guess I could just use that, even though it sounds odd. I like the other suggestion too, thanks.

Comment: Ankaŭ eblas _ĉiufoje (mal)pli_

Comment: Ah, I should have checked Tekstaro. I forgot. It just feels a little clunky to me, but I cannot argue against actual usage.

Answer (score 2):

I think

> Homoj uzas Facebook ĉiam malpli.

is a good way to say *less and less* or *decreasingly* or

> ĉiam pli malmulte